# Rename and move a file in Team Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like a script in Google Sheets to move and possibly rename a file located on Google Team Drive. So far I have found out, that "move" isn't possible, it's "add the file (copy), then delete the original". But this only works on a regular Google Drive, not a Google Team Drive. What I have tried is

```
destinationFolder.addFile(file);
sourceFolder.removeFile(file);
```

but the first line gives me an error that "Team Drive doesn't support this function".

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal of `I would like a script in Google Sheets to move and possibly rename a file located on Google Team Drive.`? In this case, you want to move only the container-bound script from Google Spreadsheet by separating from Google Docs to the shared Drive. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, It's an external file (located on Team Drive) I want to move, not a script. It's a CSV file that my script imports and I then want moved to an "imported" directory.

Comment: Hi Rubén, Yes, I got it working with that link! Thank you very much. Don't know why it didn't show up in my search…